# Can I delete the folder androidTest if I don't do test in Android studio?

Tags: android-studio

I find there is a folder named androidTest in Android studio project, Can I delete the folder androidTest if I don't do test in Android studio?

Answer (score 23):

Yes, you can delete it if you don't wanna use it.

Comment: When I deleted it, Android Studio raised a Core IDE exception in my face and after that it regenerated the test folder

Comment: @TimCastelijns What version of Android Studio? Is completely safe delete it at least until version 1.3.2. Only a Delete folder is necessary, without refactor.

Comment: 1.3.2. I managed to remove it, but i didnt expect that Core IDE exception

Comment: Mine includes 7 errors for the 7 lines of code in it since the last gradle and gradle wrapper upgrade, starting with 'cannot resolve AndroidJUnit4'.

Answer (score 19):

Yes if you don't use unit tests you can remove two package name that have **(test)** and **(androidTest)** at end.

And for reduce size of apk you can remove below library that related to *Test*

```
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

Answer (score 8):

Beside removing dependencies and folders, make sure to remove:

```
testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
```

as well, in order not to get more errors.

After removing this, my apk size reduced around 300 KB.

//Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Yes You can delete them ,you can go to `build.gradle` and then remove following dependencies which comes preloaded in any new android project.

```
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
```

and then click on the `androidTest` and `Test` package and Press `Delete` they will be removed !

Answer (score 0):

testImplementation and androidTestImplementation and androidTestImplementation does not come under Apk Size.

test part in testImplementation tells a different flavor which is not the part of release builds.

You can write test cases without increasing apk size.